# mod_headers Server

Tags: linux, centos, httpd, apache-2.2

I run a CentOS box with WHM/cPanel, and I rebuilt Apache to have mod_headers.

mod_headers works fine when I am adding new headers, but for some reason I cannot change the "Server:" header to a different value.

I have tried

```
Header unset Server
Header set Server "Test"
```

but it still does not change it in the request. Meanwhile, other header directives such as

```
Header add foo bar
```

shows up in the HTTP response.

How can I use mod_headers to change the value of the HTTP "Server:" response? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Apache version? In 1.3 and earlier mod_headers can't alter Server header, but you may alter defines in sources and recompile it.

Comment: I am running Apache/2.2.1

Comment: In what context are you using Header directive? Try to leave only `unset` directive, will the Server: header disappear? If not, this is bug,report it to CentOS maintainers

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Server: header is controlled by the **ServerTokens** directive in apache and you can set it to *Prod* to send minimal info out.

ref: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servertokens